# Why do I get Bind Variable "DeliveryDate_Variable" is NOT DECLARED(Completely New TO Oracle)

Tags: oracle, variables

I have the following script in Oacle
I do not understand why i get

Bind Variable "DeliveryDate_Variable" is NOT DECLARED

Everything looks ok to me

```
VARIABLE RollingStockTypeId_Variable NUMBER := 1;
VARIABLE DeliveryDate_Variable DATE := (to_date('2010/8/25:12:00:00AM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam'));

SELECT DISTINCT
       rs.Id,
       rs.SerialNumber,
       rsc.Name AS Category,
       (SELECT COUNT(Id) from ROLLINGSTOCKS WHERE ROLLINGSTOCKCATEGORYID = rsc.id) as "Number Owened",
       (SELECT COUNT(rs.Id)                 
       FROM ROLLINGSTOCKS rs       
       WHERE rs.ID NOT IN(  select RollingStockId 
                            from ROLLINGSTOCK_ORDER
                            WHERE :DeliveryDate_Variable  BETWEEN DEPARTUREDATE AND DELIVERYDATE)    
       AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId IN (Select Id 
                                        from RollingStockCategories 
                                        Where RollingStockTypeId = :RollingStockTypeId_Variable)
                                        AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId =     rsc.Id) AS "Number Available"
       FROM ROLLINGSTOCKS rs
       JOIN RollingStockCategories rsc ON rsc.Id = rs.RollingStockCategoryId
       WHERE rs.ID NOT IN(
                            select RollingStockId 
                            from ROLLINGSTOCK_ORDER
                            WHERE :DeliveryDate_Variable  BETWEEN DEPARTUREDATE AND DELIVERYDATE
                          )    
       AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId IN 
                          (
                            Select Id 
                            from RollingStockCategories 
                            Where RollingStockTypeId = :RollingStockTypeId_Variable 
                          )
      ORDER BY rsc.Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a definitely odd quirk of SQL*plus that [the list of allowable datatypes for variables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm#sthref3194) does not include DATE.

The solution is to declare "date" variables as varchar2(9) or barchar2(18) (depending on whether we want include the time element) and then cast the variables TO_DATE() as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I Managed to find the problem, for some reason Oracle didn't like the casting ov the sting to date (in line)

This is how i changed it

```
    VARIABLE RollingStockTypeId_Variable NUMBER; 
exec :RollingStockTypeId_Variable := 2;

VARIABLE DeliveryDate_Variable VARCHAR2(30); 
exec :DeliveryDate_Variable := '2010/8/25:12:00:00AM';

SELECT DISTINCT
       rs.Id,
       rs.SerialNumber,
       rsc.Name AS Category,
       (SELECT COUNT(Id) from ROLLINGSTOCKS WHERE ROLLINGSTOCKCATEGORYID = rsc.id) as "Number Owened",
       (SELECT COUNT(rs.Id)                 
       FROM ROLLINGSTOCKS rs       
       WHERE rs.ID NOT IN(  select RollingStockId 
                            from ROLLINGSTOCK_ORDER
                            WHERE (to_date(:DeliveryDate_Variable, 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam'))  BETWEEN DEPARTUREDATE AND DELIVERYDATE)    
       AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId IN (Select Id 
                                        from RollingStockCategories 
                                        Where RollingStockTypeId = :RollingStockTypeId_Variable)
                                        AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId =     rsc.Id) AS "Number Available"
       FROM ROLLINGSTOCKS rs
       JOIN RollingStockCategories rsc ON rsc.Id = rs.RollingStockCategoryId
       WHERE rs.ID NOT IN(
                            select RollingStockId 
                            from ROLLINGSTOCK_ORDER
                            WHERE (to_date(:DeliveryDate_Variable, 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam'))  BETWEEN DEPARTUREDATE AND DELIVERYDATE
                          )    
       AND rs.RollingStockCategoryId IN 
                          (
                            Select Id 
                            from RollingStockCategories 
                            Where RollingStockTypeId = :RollingStockTypeId_Variable 
                          )
      ORDER BY rsc.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I thought that you had to initialize VARIABLES without functions -- that is, I thought that TO_DATE was not allowed.

I think it is because the VARIABLE declaration is not really part of SQL -- it is specific to SQLPlus, and you can't drop back and forth between the tw.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` datatype is not allowed for variables declared in SQLPlus.  You have to create the variable as `varchar` and then use `to_date`.  [SQLPlus variable syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm#BACGHCJE)